# Facebook Like Box issues - my patience ended

Tags: html, facebook-like

I'm trying to set up a Like Box in this website: http://filmefilmes.com/breu
The Facebook Page of the site is: http://www.facebook.com/pages/BREU/278537375497440

I have tried all methods. iFrame, FBML, etc.
When you click the "like" button it returns a Error that says the page can't be reached.

When I pass the site on the debugger the error is:

> You have < meta> tags ouside of your < head>. This is either because
>   your < head> was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree, or
>   you accidentally put your Open Graph tags in the wrong place. Either
>   way you need to fix it before the tags are usable.

Which is incorrect because the tags are obviously inside the page's head.
And i get this warning too:

> The og:locale property should be explicitly provided, even if a value
>   can be inferred from other tags.

I have to deliver this website very soon and I've spent some hours trying to correct this and to find solutions in forums etc.
As I have changed methods I believe the error is somewhere in the markup of my page but I don't really have a clue.
Help will be heavily appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Having a quick look at the site I can see you DO have `<meta>` tags outside of the `<head>` element, these are inside a second `<head>` tag further down the page.

Check your facetek div.

Comment: Thanks for the response; well I'm seeing the page with Firebug and I see the other `head` down there but It's inside the iframe generated by the code Facebook tells me to paste. It's not hard-coded by myself...

Comment: that's strange. The like button does actually increments like count and then throws an error 'Page could not be reached'.

Answer (score 0):

few of your meta tags are unclosed. ("/>")
thus, closing  within them is parser error.
fix it and it should go fine

Comment: thanks for checking it out buddy. i have closed the tags now; but i'm  still having the same erros.

Comment: hmm, what debugger you use? validator.w3c.org does not show the errors your are talking about